# Issue with undefined namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

"xmlns="VL01" Seems to be causing the style-sheet to fail(works fine if removed), do no know how to address it the style-sheet.  I feel like this is basic XLST 101 but I am having a hard time wrapping my brain around it.  Any assisting would be greatly appreciated.  Cheers

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="VL01 http://site.com/ReportServer?%2FVMS%20Reports%2FVL01&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rs%3ASessionID=lk44ff55z5q3ck3b5pfuxo45&amp;rc%3ASchema=True"     Name="VL01"     textbox41="VL01 - Checklist Report&#xD;&#xA;"     textbox1946=" 2) Target Element&#xD;&#xA;     Target Element List&#xD;&#xA;        Windows 7&#xD;&#xA;3) Report Options&#xD;&#xA;    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="VL01">

<list2>
    <Item_Collection>
        <Item />
    </Item_Collection>
</list2>
<list1>
    <list1_Details_Group_Collection>
        <list1_Details_Group 
            Key="V0001070" 
            EffectiveDate="04 Mar 1998 16:03:47:000"
            LongName2="Name..."/>
    </list1_Details_Group_Collection>
</list1>
</Report>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="4.0" indent="yes"/> 

<xsl:variable name="var-checklist_name">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(translate(Report/@textbox1946, '&#xD;&#xA;', ''),'3)'),'Target&#x00A0;Element&#x00A0;List')"/>
</xsl:variable><xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<body>
    <table>    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Report/list1/list1_Details_Group_Collection"/>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Report/list1/list1_Details_Group_Collection">
<xsl:for-each select="list1_Details_Group">
    <Import_List>
        <Checklist_Name>    
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate($var-checklist_name, '&#x00A0;', ' '))"/>
        </Checklist_Name>
        <Vuln_ID><xsl:value-of select="number(substring-after(@VulKey,'V'))"/></Vuln_ID>
        <Short_Name><xsl:value-of select="substring(@LongName2,1,255)"/></Short_Name>
        <Release_Date><xsl:value-of select="substring(@EffectiveDate,1,11)"/></Release_Date>
    </Import_List>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the namespace in the `xsl:stylesheet` with a prefix (any prefix). Example:

```
xmlns:vl="VL01"
```

Update your paths to include the prefix. Example:

```
match="vl:Report/vl:list1/vl:list1_Details_Group_Collection"
```

---

This updated version will produce output. In addition to the namespace declaration and updating all paths with prefixes, I had to change the version in `xsl:output`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:vl="VL01">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/> 

    <xsl:variable name="var-checklist_name">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(translate(Report/@textbox1946, '&#xD;&#xA;', ''),'3)'),'Target&#x00A0;Element&#x00A0;List')"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>    
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="vl:Report/vl:list1/vl:list1_Details_Group_Collection"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="vl:Report/vl:list1/vl:list1_Details_Group_Collection">
        <xsl:for-each select="vl:list1_Details_Group">
            <Import_List>
                <Checklist_Name>    
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate($var-checklist_name, '&#x00A0;', ' '))"/>
                </Checklist_Name>
                <Vuln_ID><xsl:value-of select="number(substring-after(@VulKey,'V'))"/></Vuln_ID>
                <Short_Name><xsl:value-of select="substring(@LongName2,1,255)"/></Short_Name>
                <Release_Date><xsl:value-of select="substring(@EffectiveDate,1,11)"/></Release_Date>
            </Import_List>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @SoBeK - Did you update all of the paths? If I have a minute, I'll try it myself and see if there is anything else wrong.

Comment: yes (thank you for the quick reply btw)

Modified XSL
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:vl="VL01">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>    
                <xsl:apply-templates select="vl:Report/vl:list1/vl:list1_Details_Group_Collection"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: copied and tested working example, no success.  I am performing an input function in Microsoft access (don't hate) and applying the stylesheet (transform option).  I have used this method countless times without an issue, if your example works it does not seem to be compatible with ms access.  Ideas?

Comment: @SoBeK - Sorry I don't have any ideas. Hopefully someone will have a solution for you soon.